# Как сделать цвета в консоли Ruby?

Tags: ruby, color

хочу сделать красивый текст в консоли, но не могу найти гем для этого

Есть ли для руби какой нибудь аналог в руби, того же `rich` в `python` ?

Comment: Присмотритесь, может поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489183/how-can-i-use-ruby-to-colorize-the-text-output-to-a-terminal

Answer (score 0):

Есть шикарный инструмент для поиска гемов, и там есть нужная тебе категория

https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Terminal_Coloring